# cannot send file over bluetooth on windows 8 pro; missing bluetooth file transfer

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I recently performed a clean install of windows 8 pro on my asus ux31a.  I was trying to send some pictures to my phone over bluetooth.  I already scoured the net for some solution and I came up empty.  I already checked the bluetooth service and it is in automatic, I sent files from my phone to my pc and it worked.  However, when I try to send a file from my pc to the phone there is no option for bluetooth file transfer.

It is not on the right click+send to option
It is not on the charm bar+search+apps
It is not on the right click+bluetooth icon on the taskbar

its frustrating! I even reinstalled my drivers in case it will help.

Thannks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In windows XP, you could have used [squirt.exe](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/4051-windows-xp-transferring-files-via-bluetooth). Type `fsquirt` at the command line to see if it still exists in windows 8.

Comment: I just learned about `fsquirt` and it works great in Windows 8.1.